# Tomcat 6 URL Rewrite translate all occurences of character to a different one

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite requests for http://www.example.com/foo/bar/moo to http://www.example.com/foo@bar@moo with Tomcat 6.

The reason is, that the application JIRA batches multiple included javascripts into a single batch.js and disallows the usage of subpaths. But the javascripts themselves dynamically load resources from these subpaths. I don't want to change these javascripts so I can easily upgrade the javascripts when it's necessary.

Batching can't be disabled and so I would like to translate the requests to ones with / replaced by a different delimiter (which doesn't occur naturally in these URLs).
In JIRA I already renamed (mapped) the resources to the new names.

Now for tomcat I thought of something like `urlrewrite`:

```
<urlrewrite>
  <rule enabled="true">
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="equal">^/foo/.*</condition>
    <from>/</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">...</to>
  </rule>
<urlrewrite>
```

But don't know how to specify the `<to/>` if possible at all.
If  can't do that, what other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only a finite number n of possible slashes, a workaround is to multiply the rule n times.

```
<rule enabled="true"> 
    <condition type="request-url" operator="equal">/(jira)/(dojo|dojox|dijit)/([^/]+)$</condition> 
    <from>^/(dojo|dojox|dijit)/([^/]+)$</from> 
    <to type="redirect">/%1/%2@%3</to> 
</rule> 

<rule enabled="true"> 
    <condition type="request-url" operator="equal">/(jira)/(dojo|dojox|dijit)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$</condition> 
    <from>^/(dojo|dojox|dijit)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$</from> 
    <to type="redirect">/%1/%2@%3@%4</to> 
</rule>
```

P.S.: The original problem actually isn't a problem, because all redirects have to go the batch.js so you need only 1 rule for the JIRA problem.